# procedural generate mesh that fits each other

Tags: mesh, procedural

is it possible to generate mesh just like the one in the picture? if so, how?

I have to make a whole bunch of those for a project i'm working one and they don't need to be handmade but they do need to fit each other

[image: The kind of shape to generate]

Comment: Why not use a the Cell fracture addon to break up your master outline object, then shrink each piece using a deform modifier with a negative value.

Comment: In fact watching this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DEo_9AopfoQ I see at 10 mins there is a reference to a element margin to define the gap between generated elements.

Comment: @3pointedit it work like a charm, exactly what I needed, thanks

Comment: Thats great! I have rewritten my response into an answer, could you please accept it ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a the Cell fracture addon - [Fracture addon](https://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Extensions:2.6/Py/Scripts/Object/Fracture) - to break up your master outline object, then shrink each piece using a deform modifier with a negative value, OR use the margin variable in the script preferences to create a gap between elements.
Check out this tutorial if you are stuck - [Cell Fracture addon tut](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DEo_9AopfoQ)